# How to exit a 'while' loop in OVM / verilog after checking for a specific timeout condition

Tags: while-loop, timeout, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I have a 'while' loop as part of an OVM test that looks like this:

```
while (signal_val == 0) begin
    signal_val  = sla_vpi_get_value_by_name ("blah");
end
```

I want to restrict this loop for 120 microseconds only and exit after that. I want to quit the test if (signal_val == 0) is still not being satisfied at the end of 120µs. How do I achieve this?

I figured I'll have to call the 'global_stop_request()' to quit from the test, but trying to check the existing condition in the while loop for a fixed timeout value (120µs) seems to be tricky. Also, 'break' does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

Tried using 'break' this way, but 'break' gives a syntax error:

```
while (signal_val == 0) begin
    signal_val  = sla_vpi_get_value_by_name ("blah");
    #120us;
    break;
end
```

Comment: how is 'break' not working? how did you apply it?

Comment: But I realized 2 things here: 1. 'break' gives a syntax error. 2. A delay of 120 microseconds is being added, but the condition is not being checked for 120 microseconds.

Comment: What kind of an error message did you get?

Comment: Is `sla_vpi_get_value_by_name` time consuming task? If it is not, time will not persist as it would be in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Serge It is a typical syntax error message reading: Syntax error at line XYZ near 'break'.

Comment: @Greg Not sure what you mean by a time consuming task, this function is used in a lot of places in the test to get some signal names from the hardware system hierarchy.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using 'fork-join' or 'fork-disable'? I'm not sure how either would work here, with the required time constraint. Any suggestions?

Comment: @chmod which verilog compiler do you use? is it in a system verilog mode at all? Where is this **while** loop used? is it inside of a class member or in a module somewhere?

Comment: @Serge I'm using the synopsis package and VCS simulator. Yes, it does support SV as well.

Comment: Just realized that 'fork-join_any' is not recognized as a valid syntax either :'( the simulator likes only 'fork-join'.

Comment: @chmod i just tried it with vcs 2017.03. it compiles without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work as you are expecting. Let us take a look:

```
while (signal_val == 0) begin
    signal_val  = sla_vpi_get_value_by_name ("blah");
    #120us;
    break;
end
```

`signal_val` is evaluated initially just once at the while statement, and since it is 0, you enter the while loop

`signal_val` gets the value returned by your function call. This happens at the same simulation cycle as the previous evaluation of while. Assuming that there is no change, you get 0 as the return value again

Now, the function waits 120us

Finally, it breaks out of while loop. `signal_val` isn't evaluated again.

To achieve the functionality you want, you would need to use `fork...join` and a watchdog task

```
fork
  begin: wait_signal_val
    while (signal_val == 0) begin
      signal_val  = sla_vpi_get_value_by_name ("blah");
      if (signal_val == 1) begin
        `uvm_info(get_name(), "YES!! signal_val was seen as 1", UVM_LOW);
      end
      else begin 
        #20ns; // (or some clocking mechanism)
      end
    end
  end

  begin: watchdog
    #120us;
    `uvm_fatal(get_name(), "NOPE!! signal_val is still 0 after 120us. Killing test");
  end
join_any
disable fork
```

In the above code, either `watchdog` or `wait_signal_val` finishes. When that happens, the fork...join_any completes and disables the fork.

I use this a lot in my testbench for functionality like you describe and it works seamlessly.

Comment: Got it! I just coded something similar by searching high and low on this issue just before you replied. Do you think this is similar? And which approach is better?     '*fork 
       looping_code; //process 1
       #120us;       //process 2
join_any
global_stop_request();*'

Comment: Hey if it does the job, it's good! Your solution looks more elegant. If you liked the answer, please accept :)